# How to access navigation property collection in ValidationAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

In the `IsValid` function of a class implementing the `ValidationAttribute`, I am getting the value of another property by using this code:

```
Dim AccessToRoomsinfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("AccessToRooms")
Dim AccessToRooms = 
    Convert.ChangeType(
        AccessToRoomsinfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, Nothing), 
        GetType(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses
            .EntityCollection(Of CM_CONTRACTACTIVATIONACCESSTOROOM)))
```

But when I inspect `AccessToRooms` in the Watch window, the collection is empty.

How can I access this collection?

Comment: would you like to see the c# code plus can you post your whole function i mean with the parameters.